# Hiding UI Element behind Other UI Elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, uielement

I'm having a problem with my UI Elements. I am spawning in enemies who have health bars which stay on top of them. The problem is, that if those health bars move through the position of other UI Elements i have (let's say the "Main Menu Button") they get rendered **on top** of that Element, not **behind it**.

[image: It looks like this]

I managed to spawn the healthbars in a different canvas so they don't interfere with the button itself by blocking raycasts but i can't manage to layer them behind the button (which changes position during gameplay too).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one canvas you can control the order of them using the *sort order* property in the canvas component.
[image: Sort order screenshot]

Comment: That did the trick. Glad i don't have to fiddle around with the hierarchy!

Comment: Good for you :)